# When am I supposed to start and end my node.js SQL connection and should I just use pooling from the get go?

Tags: javascript, express, node-mysql

I'm starting my first Express web app. I'm not quite understanding the logic of when/where to start my SQL connection and when I'm supposed to end it.

Copy pasting projects online to get started, I had a connect and close inside the same db.js file. It seems that no matter where it's required, it instantly creates a connection. Whether it's in the APP.JS entry point, or just the fact that it's required by a certain model file.

So removing the connection.end() method solved my issue of not being able to insert query because of "cannot enqueue query after invoking quit". But if I connect and end manually after the function insert, i need to create a NEW database object, or the connect() won't even work.

Where am I REALLY supposed to "start" the connection. From the require in the app.js? Does it even matter since it starts from any require anywhere? When do I type the connection.end() command? It's not like a desktop app, so killing the node server on VS Code just ends it anyways.

I just don't get it, the Node.js documentation doesn't really spell it out for me. Should I use pooling? Where do I close the connection? Why one way or the other? I really tried to google it, but nothing goes over the why and where conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, database connections should be created just before your query executes and closed straight after.

Long lived database connections can drain the server of resources, and may cause connection limit exhaustion (there is usually a cap set by the client driver). The more concurrent use you have in the application, the more prone you are to long lived connections causing problems.

Creating a connection from scratch is a resource and time consuming process. So you should definitely be using connection pooling which makes the "creation" of a connection a fast operation of simply grabbing an available connection from the pool.

By releasing the connection as soon as possible back to the pool, you free it up for other workers to use.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/142068/167591

Comment: Well pooling seems to be the way to go because if i use the connection.end() tag then I have to create a new connection object everytime. From what I gathered theres just always going to be a pool of connections running as necessary. It just seems odd to me because my require function is the one kicking off the connection, because require in node runs the script. So essentially I never need to use the connect function command to start it. That's what also is puzzling from a design perspective, considering the tutorials explicitly show those commands.